# What does it mean Accessibility Status Changed: On?

Tags: iphone, sdk, debugging

Making my app over two weeks. But only now I received a message in debugger:

> Accessibility Status Changed: On
>   Loading AX for: com.yourcompany.XXXXXXXX

What is it? Am I doing something wrong? And if I'm not - why I received that today?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but this line seems to turn up when an app makes use of certain connectivity hardware such as Bluetooth. And it's a good thing to see! It stopped turning up in my app and now I can't get it to connect to anything.

-Ash